# EnumerateFiles on subfolders memory efficiency

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

i have 2 million files distributed in subfolders partitioned to years and months.
i am looping over the files using:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(data_path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

should i expect that partitioning the enumerated set by using a nested construct:

```
foreach (string year_folder in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(data_path))
    foreach (string month_folder in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(year_folder))
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(month_folder))
```

would be more memory efficient?

please see also my comment below.

Comment: Im really keen to hear the outcome of this, if you find a more efficient way of doing this ill add it to my fluent System.IO wrapper

Comment: You should try both and find out; you have the code written on both cases, so just profile a run of each and you'll know for sure.  Even if others theorize which is better, it's rather hard to theorize *how much* better one is.  It rather likely that the difference is so small as to not be of major concern.

Comment: what i am trying to understand is whether the IEnumerable set takes up memory until the loop iterates over the last element (justifying the second approach), or whether garbage collection is done more frequently while in the loop (and then the two approaches are similar)

Comment: thanks @Gabe, could you provide a reference for that?

Answer (score 1):

**Yours is slightly smaller**

Your proposed solution will be *slightly* more memory efficient, even if only because you can hard code the fact that there are exactly three nesting levels, that the first two are directories only, and the final one contains only files.

**Theirs is slightly more general**

On the other hand, `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` must implement a solution for the general case with arbitrary directory nesting (which will involve its own internal stack for keeping track of where it is in the enumeration).

**Either one's fine, here are the tradeoffs**

Your implementation binds your code to your current, specific directory structure. I kinda *like* being able to glance at your foreach loops and visualize what the folder structure is that it expects to find on disk.

On the other hand, that'll be a nuisance if you or someone on your team wants to change the directory layout. If it's either extremely unlikely to change it or simple enough to update your code if you *do* change your directory structure, seems safe to use your approach.